# SQL Case Statement Logic Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to get the logic in case statement to work. In plain English I am saying "If the Qty in the first table is greater than ALOS in the second table, I want to run this calculation:

```
DRG_Rate=DRG_Rate + ([GMC Claims 2019].Qty-BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.ALOS)* BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier
```

I got the Join to work and it is returning the DRG's that match in both tables along with the DRG_Rate. Now I want to adjust the DRG_Rate based on the conditional statement above. If y'all need additional info let me know. I appreciate any guidance, I'm pretty new to SQL!

**Desired Result Would be: The 11513.43 rate from the second table + (15-8)* 2014.85 = 27,632.23

The 15 is the QTY in the first table, the 8 is the ALOS from the second table, the 2014.85 is the per diem outlier in the second table
**

Here is my attempt:

```sql
SELECT 

CASE
DRG_Rate

WHEN [GMC Claims 2019].Qty > BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.ALOS 
THEN DRG_Rate=DRG_Rate + ([GMC Claims 2019].Qty-BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.ALOS)* BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier

FROM [GMC Claims 2019] LEFT JOIN BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS ON
[GMC Claims 2019].DRG=BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
WHERE [GMC Claims 2019].DRG=BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.DRG_Code
```

And my tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [GMC Claims 2019] (
   
    PatNo INT NOT NULL ,
    PName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    HSSV VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DateOfService INT,
    InsName VARCHAR(50),
    DRG INT,
    RevCode INT,
    CPT VARCHAR(50),
    Qty INT  , 
    BilledCharges DECIMAL (9,2) NOT NULL,
       
);



INSERT INTO [GMC Claims 2019] (PatNo, PName, HSSV, DateOfService, InsName, DRG, RevCode, CPT, Qty, BilledCharges)

VALUES (5, 'Hisham', 'SIP', 5, 'BCBS', 439, 344, '44', 15, 500), 
;

CREATE TABLE [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] (
   
    DRG INT NOT NULL ,
    ServiceCat VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL ,
    Pmt DECIMAL (8,2) NOT NULL       
);

INSERT INTO [BCBS DRG CARVE OUT 07012016] (DRG, ServiceCat, Pmt)

VALUES (28, 'DRG Carve Out', 13537),
 (29, 'DRG Carve Out', 13537),
 (30, 'DRG Carve Out', 13537),
 (101, 'DRG Carve Out', 13537);
 
 CREATE TABLE BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS(
   DRG_Code                   INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,Description                VARCHAR(200)
  ,DRG_Weight                 NUMERIC(8,5) NOT NULL
  ,ALOS                       INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,High_Trim                  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Effective_Date             DATE 
  ,DRG_Rate                   NUMERIC(9,2) NOT NULL
  ,Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS(DRG_Code,Description,DRG_Weight,ALOS,High_Trim,Effective_Date,DRG_Rate,Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier) VALUES (439,'DISORDERS OF PANCREAS EXCEPT MALIGNANCY W CC',0.86230,4,7,NULL,11513.43,2014.85);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the sense you are conditionally adding a value to the existing DRG rate so I'm expressing this as an adjustment that is typically zero. Either way your problem was mostly syntactical.

```
DRG_Rate +
CASE WHEN [GMC Claims 2019].Qty > BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.ALOS 
    THEN ([GMC Claims 2019].Qty - BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.ALOS) * BCBS_DRG_REIMBURS.Per_Diem_High_Trim_Outlier
    ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Yeah that worked, just a syntax error. Thanks !